# Ошибка django - render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'renderer'

Tags: django, django-admin

Пытаюсь реализовать теги на **django**. Подключил модуль **taggit**, добавил менеджер тэгов `TaggableManager` в свою модель, всё по инструкции, только почему то перестал работать переход на статью в админке django, если убрать `TaggableManager` всё работает. Текст ошибки - render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'renderer'.
Уже два часа ломаю голову.

```
tags = TaggableManager() - это добавил
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52039654/django-typeerror-render-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-renderer

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `pip install django_taggit==0.22.2` вводим последний `django_taggit`.

На данный период так:

```
pip install django_taggit==1.2.0
```